# Is it possible to change the site's design/theme (I mean the way the site looks)?

Tags: feature-request

The current look is a bit pale, and not particularly aesthetic. I would recommend something more of the MathOverFlow look, where colors are a bit stronger. Is there a way to change the current look?

Comment: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-should-our-logo-and-design-be

Comment: I see then. This is just a temporary look, suited for the beta phase only.

Comment: Amusing, I thought I was a bit queasy about the sketchy look and feel, but it's kind of grown on me and I almost really-like-it by now :)

Comment: @Neeldhara: Me too.  I guess that we have to think hard to come up with something better than the current “design.”  It is sketchy, but very consistent about its sketchiness.